# Android ndk remove "lib" prefix

Tags: compiler-construction, android-ndk, native

I am compiling some native code in to a library to use in my app. Everything works fine but something bugging me.

Output of native code gets "lib" prefix added to it so "mylibrary"  becomes "libmylibrary.so" and I have toad it as "mylibrary"

Can't I remove this prefix? This might sound odd but keep in mind that I have zero knowledge on compiling native code or on c for that matter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The <kbd>"lib"</kbd> prefix is a naming convention in Unix since the early days. This prefix is required when the shared object is used by the linker with <kbd>-l</kbd> flag, see more [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6561273/is-liblibrary-name-a-so-a-naming-convention-for-static-libraries-in-linux). The prefix is implied in Java, too, when you use [System.loadLibrary()](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/System.html#loadLibrary(java.lang.String)). The prefix is also expected by Android [ApkBuilder](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/sdk/+/e162064a7b5db1eecec34271bc7e2a4296181ea6/sdkmanager/libs/sdklib/src/com/android/sdklib/build/ApkBuilder.java#) and the system installer (see details [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17384650/192373)).

But if you really want to name you file <kbd>"mylibrary.so"</kbd>, it is possible to create such file, and load it in Java with [System.load(fullpath)](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/System.html#load(java.lang.String)). You will take care of deployment of this file yourself.