# /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lliburing

Tags: c, io-uring

When compiled using

```
gcc liburing-test.c -o liburing-test -lliburing
```

flowing error is displayed

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lliburing
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can fix this error by replacing `-lliburing` with `-luring`

```
gcc liburing-test.c -o liburing-test -luring
```

[Is lib{library name}.a / .so a naming convention for static libraries in Linux?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6561273/is-liblibrary-name-a-so-a-naming-convention-for-static-libraries-in-linux)

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who runs across this and uses CMake add `uring` to `target_link_libraries()` in your CMakeLists.txt.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).